# Помогите, пожалуйста, найти предложение, где оборот не нужно обособлять

Tags: запятые, недопустимая-метка, правила, тесты

A) Охваченный каким-то неясным
предчувствием, он быстро оделся и
вышел из дому.

B) Изнурённый тяжёлой болезнью, старик
вошёл в комнату.

C) Утомлённые маминой чистоплотностью,
ребята приучались хитрить.

D) Убаюканный сладкими надеждами, он
крепко спал.

E) Оглушённый ударом кулака, он сначала
зашатался на месте.

Comment: Сабина, попробуйте сами найти решение и хотя бы предположить, почему так, и тогда Вам ответят, исправят, если будет нужно. Ведь здесь не выполняют задания. Если ответов будет несколько, Вы сможете принять один из них галочкой слева от него.

Comment: Сабина пробовала, но не нашла. Ей казалось, что все запятые поставлены правильно. А меня зачем минусовали?  Я сама с третьего раза только нашла.  Предложение было удачно замаскировано, составители постарались.

Comment: @Sharon, это не я, честно, могу скриншот прислать. Сейчас ответ прочитаю... Прочитал, отплюсовал. А вы откуда знаете, что Сабина не нашла? На другой площадке?

Comment: Спасибо! Нет, это такой психологический прием...    А задание действительно трудное. Сравните: Изнурённый тяжёлой болезнью,  старик с трудом вошёл в комнату. Здесь уже нужна запятая.

Comment: @Sharon Может, и трудное, но не для меня :))) я его сразу решил. Ну вот и мой плюс вопросу тоже превратился в ноль... Поставьте и вы, задание действительно не из элементарных.

Comment: Ну не знаю, этот старик здорово замаскировался...

Answer (score 1):

***Изнурённый тяжёлой болезнью старик вошёл в комнату.***

Оборот стоит **перед** определяемым словом (существительным) и **не имеет** дополнительного обстоятельственного значения, поэтому он не обособляется.

В остальных предложениях оборот относится **к местоимению** (всегда обособляется), а также  имеет дополнительное причинное значение. И только в предложении В эти факторы отсутствуют.